# Stuck Embedding CSS Link in HTML Page For SharePoint

Tags: css, pages

I have a custom HTML page that is a single page that takes in WebParts. It is a new WebParts interface and there is no WebPart for adding and hiding HTML.

I have added a  in the head section of the HTML and when you load the page the CSS is not loaded. Looking at the code there is no reference to the stylesheet.

Both the CSS and the Site Page are published and the correct version for both appear to be being pulled when you visit their URL.

I have tried adding a new Master Page but that has been nothing but trouble. I just need to adjust some simple CSS for this page.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Can you please add the code snippet, how you have added reference to your CSS file?

Comment: Thank you @Genesh Sanap I added  <link rel"stylesheet" href="https://site.sharepoint.com/Style%20Library/custom.css" /> in the <head> section of the HTML. - Josh

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, there is a typo in your code. It should be like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<path of css file>" />
```

Also check in browser's console if there is any file not found error because of wrong path of css file.

Comment: I have this and the CSS is still not there. I would add a screenshot but I cannot.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that these were NEW (After 2016) pages so the CSS was not being used by Microsoft at all.